# Javascript push() and pop() arrays for undo in sprite editor

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, graphics, stack

I'm creating a Javascript port of a sprite editor for a DOS game I'm making so that artistic friends can help me out with artwork.

Everything so far is working well but I'm not a Javascript developer by trade and my undo feature that I expected to be pretty easy has me stumped and I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting it.

Essentially, I have a 64000 element array that contains the screen data for the screen, another that contains values identifying which pixels have changed from frame to frame and need to be drawn called "vblt" or V-Blit.

When the user's mousebutton changes back to unclicked in the drawing area, I capture an undo point by pushing the "vram" or Video RAM  array into the "hstr" or History array and if it's greater than 10 deep, I cull the oldest one:

```
if(omouse-mouseButton>0 && (ymouse>=25)){
    hstr.push(vram);
    if (hstr.length>10){
        var junk = hstr.shift();
    }
    console.log(hstr.length);
}
```

When the user presses the ESC key, I want to pop the last added state back into VRAM:

```
if(key==27 && hstr.length>0){
    vram = hstr.pop();
    for(addr=0;addr<64000;addr++){
        vblt[addr]=3;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not working the way I'd like it to (at all) and I never expected to get stuck at this point in writing the code, I'd appreciate any advice anyone has. Thanks!

PS. I did a typeof on the array and it returns "object." Why is this? Do I need to be more specific or can't I do typeof against an array?

Comment: Can you tell us which is the array you have a problem with and can you tell us what its value is when you do a console.log on it?

Comment: console.log(hstr);
VM1060:1 (10) [Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000)]

Comment: What is displayed if you console.log(hstr[0])?

Comment: I'm not sure what this undefined is: again, I'm not experienced with JavaScript so I might be missing something obvious here:

console.log(hstr);
VM1060:1 (10) [Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000), Array(64000)]
undefined

Comment: This actually looks correct: console.log(hstr[0]);
VM1071:1 (64000) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 9, 9, 9, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 11, 11, 11, 0, 12, 12, 12, 0, 13, 13, ...  It's the top of the palette/color selector.

Comment: The sprite editor is here if you want to see everything: https://robtalada.com/apps/entity-editor5/

Comment: The undefined comes from the return value of console.log. To not be alarmed by that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168506/discussion-between-robert-talada-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally get this working.

I got around my problem by encoding the array into a string which I'd push/pop in and out of the hstr array and also save to localStorage.

**Save Undo State:**

```
        if(omouse-mouseButton>0 && (ymouse>=25)){

            var tempStr = "";
            for(i=0;i<56000;i++){
                tempStr += String.fromCharCode((vram[i+(8000)]));
            }

            hstr.push(localStorage.getItem('FTHSPRITE_'+mapx+'_'+mapy+'_21CE27FA45476C99F7FC1C8D0D9D910245CCFB008E9F91DEDA0DCDD344DD46BD'));
            localStorage['FTHSPRITE_'+mapx+'_'+mapy+'_21CE27FA45476C99F7FC1C8D0D9D910245CCFB008E9F91DEDA0DCDD344DD46BD'] = tempStr;
            localStorage['FTHSPRITE_UNDO_'+mapx+'_'+mapy+'_21CE27FA45476C99F7FC1C8D0D9D910245CCFB008E9F91DEDA0DCDD344DD46BD'] = hstr;

            if (hstr.length>10){
                var junk = hstr.shift();
            }
        }
```

**Restore Undo State:**

```
                if(key==27 && hstr.length >= 1){
                    var temp = hstr.pop();
                    for(i=0;i<56000;i++){
                            vram[i+(8000)] = temp.charCodeAt(i);
                            vblt[i+(8000)] = 3;
                    }
                    var tempStr = "";
                    for(i=0;i<56000;i++){
                        tempStr += String.fromCharCode((vram[i+(8000)]));
                    }
                    localStorage['FTHSPRITE_'+mapx+'_'+mapy+'_21CE27FA45476C99F7FC1C8D0D9D910245CCFB008E9F91DEDA0DCDD344DD46BD'] = tempStr;
                }
```

Comment: In a later version, I discovered that the localStorage bit wasn't working so I broke it out to create a localStorage item for each element in the hstr Array. That is not reflected here because it wasn't part of my solution when I solved the problem.